# Make root folders stand out in explorer for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a workspace in VSCode with multiple root folders open. If I have two or more root folders open, it's very hard to see which files are in which folder. Take the following screenshot, for example:

[image]

`voting-app` is a root folder (the one above it is outside of view). At a glance, it's very hard to tell. Is there an extension for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [feature request pending](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37979) for easier customization of the root folders. You might want to upvote it to give it more prominence.

For now, icon themes can style the root folder, as seen in the [Minimal icon theme](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/theme-defaults/fileicons/vs_minimal-icon-theme.json), so you could activate a different icon set that supports this, or create your own.

Comment: currently closed as "out of scope" and to groom the backlog.