# How to make root folders stand out in VS Code's explorer with these outlined circle icons?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a workspace in VS Code with multiple root folders open. If I have two or more root folders open, it's very hard to see which files are in which folder.
Recently I cam across someone's VS Code where the root folders icon is different than normal folder. The root folder has an icon of circle with a dot inside if it is a closed folder, just a circle if it is a open folder.  Attaching a screenshot of the icons of root folders (COPR and Nodepen are two root folders which are closed).  How can I get these ? I usually prefer light themes, are there any light themes which already have this?[image]

Comment: search the marketplace for `Folder Theme`

Comment: search the marketplace for `File and Folder Theme`, you can now specify special icons for special folders

Comment: this question is specifically about the icons, but for anyone who wants _any_ way of making the root folders stand out more, see [Make root folders stand out in explorer for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51578984/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

That's what you get when you use workspace files / [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)- not when you use regular workspace folders.

If you want to customize the icon,

- for regular folders, you can use an icon theme
- for multi-root workspace root folders, since VS Code 1.84, thanks to [this change](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/195319), you can use a [file icon theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme) for that as well, as long as the icon theme supports it.